# How to divide all values in nested list by 2.54 In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Can you please help me to the division of nested list values in Flutter?

I have a nested list representing boy head circumference data in centimeters. For each list in the outer collection, and for each element in the inner lists, I retrieve the original circumference value in centimeters. Following that, I convert the circumference value from centimeters to inches by dividing it by 2.54. Subsequently, I updated the nested list with the converted circumference value in inches.

```
  List boyHeadCircumferenceData = [
    [
      31.92128,
      34.94019,
      36.78314,
      38.14913,
      39.24371,
      40.14288,
      40.88935,
      41.51388,
      42.03988,
      42.48701,
      42.8715,
      43.20496,
      43.49653
    ],
    [
      32.37241,
      35.35495,
      37.19961,
      38.56898,
      39.66775,
      40.57167,
      41.32285,
      41.95185,
      42.48206,
      42.93322,
      43.3214,
      43.65819,
      43.95282
    ],
    [
      32.83389,
      35.77923,
      37.62565,
      38.99847,
      40.10153,
      41.01031,
      41.76631,
      42.39988,
      42.93439,
      43.38967,
      43.78163,
      44.12182,
      44.41958,
    ],
    [
      33.60502,
      36.48819,
      38.33754,
      39.71613,
      40.82636,
      41.74325,
      42.5073,
      43.14851,
      43.69022,
      44.15237,
      44.55065,
      44.89654,
      45.19953,
    ],
    [
      34.4618,
      37.2759,
      39.1285,
      40.5135,
      41.6317,
      42.5576,
      43.3306,
      43.9803,
      44.53,
      44.9998,
      45.4051,
      45.7573,
      46.0661,
    ],
    [
      35.31858,
      38.06361,
      39.91946,
      41.31087,
      42.43704,
      43.37195,
      44.1539,
      44.81209,
      45.36978,
      45.84723,
      46.25955,
      46.61806,
      46.93267,
    ],
    [
      36.08971,
      38.77257,
      40.63135,
      42.02853,
      43.16187,
      44.10489,
      44.89489,
      45.56072,
      46.12561,
      46.60993,
      47.02857,
      47.39278,
      47.71262,
    ],
    [
      36.55119,
      39.19685,
      41.05739,
      42.45802,
      43.59565,
      44.54353,
      45.33835,
      46.00875,
      46.57794,
      47.06638,
      47.4888,
      47.85641,
      48.17938,
    ],
    [
      37.0023239,
      39.6116079,
      41.4738623,
      42.8778679,
      44.0196943,
      44.9723182,
      45.771846,
      46.4467152,
      47.0201176,
      47.5125888,
      47.9387046,
      48.3096422,
      48.6356671,
    ]
  ];
```

I need to divide these values by 2.54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void main() {
  List boyHeadCircumferenceData = [...];
  
  convertCircumferenceToInches(boyHeadCircumferenceData);
  
  for(int i = 0; i < boyHeadCircumferenceData.length; i++){
    print("$i ${boyHeadCircumferenceData[i]}");
  }
}

void convertCircumferenceToInches(List circumferenceData) {
  for (int i = 0; i < circumferenceData.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < circumferenceData[i].length; j++) {
      circumferenceData[i][j] /= 2.54;
    }
  }
}
```